# Neural Network guesses no number for MNIST dataset

Tags: machine-learning, mnist

I have built my own neural network in java. 
Its neuron layers follow this structure: 784(inputs), 200, 80, 10(outputs)

After feeding it the MNIST training data in 300 batches of 100 randomly selected images, updating weights and biases after each batch. With a learning rate of .005. However, the network seems to adopt a strategy of giving an output of all zeros every time. Because just saying 
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
is much closer to 
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
than any actual guessing strategy that it tried. On occasion, it will attempt to change but can never find a strategy that works better than that of just saying zero for everything. 
Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Does it need more training data? Does this mean there's an error in the backpropagation function I wrote?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: MNIST training data amount is more than enough. For sure you have some bug in the implementation but without the code people here can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your data label is integer encoded
2. Make sure the final `Dense` layer has `10` units with a `softmax` activation function.
3. Compile your model with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function.